# How to persist navigationItem.titleView between screen?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am using NavigationController to manage three screens. All three screens share a common image as title. I set the image in the viewWillAppear in each VC as follow:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = myImageView
```

The problem is whenever a screen is pushed/popped, the navigation is animated and a new image will come from right or left. I want the image to persist and remain in the middle none-animated.

Is there a way to disable this animation?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=uinavigationcontroller+titleview&*

Answer (score 0):

It's reproducible, only if you place/setting titleView code in `viewWillAppear`. it's moving because viewWillAppear called during forth(push) & back(pop) both operation. Set it into `viewDidLoad`, it will fix this issue

```
override fun viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 self.navigationItem.titleView = myImageView
}
```

One more alternate solution for this problem is

```
var isViewDidLoadCalled = false

override fun viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     isViewDidLoadCalled = true
}

override fun viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super. viewWillAppear(animated)

     if (isViewDidLoadCalled) {
       self.navigationItem.titleView = myImageView
       isViewDidLoadCalled = false
     }

 }
```

I recommend to use, viewDidLoad to setup your titleView

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It did not work, unfortunately. After I moved the code to viewDidLoad, the animation remains the same. A new mage is seemed pushed in.

Comment: There is only one choice to achieve your goal, Push view controller without animation. But it will stop animation for contents of view also.

Answer (score 0):

Another hard but feasible solution is:

You need to use the **UINavigationController** delegate methods to find out when the **UIViewController** is being shown. Then for each UIViewController, need to make a boolean variable like **isInitialized** property, which help you to determine when the UIViewController is being pushed on the stack, or when it's being shown upon back of next view controller.

*Your FirstViewController:*

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            if self.isInitialized {
                var navigationBarAnimation = CATransition()
                navigationBarAnimation.duration = 1.5
                navigationBarAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
                navigationBarAnimation.type = kCATransitionFade
                navigationBarAnimation.subtype = kCATransitionFade
                navigationBarAnimation.removedOnCompletion = true
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.layer?.addAnimation(navigationBarAnimation, forKey: nil)

             } else {
                    self.isInitialized = true;
             }
        }
}

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            if self.isInitialized {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.layer?.removeAllAnimations()
            }
        }
    }
```

*Your SecondViewController:*

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            if !self.isInitialized {
                var navigationBarAnimation = CATransition()
                navigationBarAnimation.duration = 1.5
                navigationBarAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
                navigationBarAnimation.type = kCATransitionFade
                navigationBarAnimation.subtype = kCATransitionFade
                navigationBarAnimation.removedOnCompletion = true
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.layer?.addAnimation(navigationBarAnimation, forKey: nil)
                        self.isInitialized = true;
                }
        }
}

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            if self.isInitialized {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.layer?.removeAllAnimations()
            }
        }
 }
```